# Rails - count query while joining three tables to one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, count

I have a fairly straightforward query that I can't seem to get right....

My model:

- User - has many Friendships (with other users)
- User - has many submissions
- User - has many comments
- User - has many votes

I need a count that represents

> All current_user's friends, whose submissions, comments or votes created_at dates are > current_user.last_refresh_date

Right now, I am building up an array by iterating over friendships and adding all submissions, comment and votes.  I then re-iterate this built-up array while comparing the dates to determine if the count should be incremented. Not the most ideal solution.

**Edit**:

@TobiasCohen

Efficient solution.  Thanks!

Followup:

I wish to add yet one more count to the present query.  I need to count all new comments & votes on the current_user.submissions that are not part of the original count (ie. not a friend).

Psuedo-code :

> current_user.submissions.join(:comments, :votes, :friends).where('last_activity >? AND friend_id != ?', current_user.last_refresh_date, current_user.id).count

I can't quite get the query correct (new to complex queries via active record).

I was going to make it a separate query and then add it to the original count.  Can it be absorbed into one query instead of two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd get the best results by adding a cache column on User, let's call it `:last_activity_at`, then update this with an  `after_create` callback on Submission, Comment and Vote.

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :update_user_last_activity_at

  private
    def update_user_last_activity_at
      user.update_attribute :last_activity_at, Time.now
    end
end
```

You could then fetch users simply with:

```
current_user.friends.where('last_activity_at > ?', current_user.last_refresh_date)
```